# Select specific column data to geom point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
Date                ID  Value
10-Apr-17 12:02:30  A   4.107919756
10-Apr-17 12:02:31  A   4.107539119
10-Apr-17 12:02:32  A   5.503949115
10-Apr-17 12:02:33  B   5.842728032
10-Apr-17 12:02:34  B   8.516053634
10-Apr-17 12:02:35  B   1.515112486
10-Apr-17 12:02:36  B   5.224667007
```

I want to plot geom_point using only the column ID == 'A'.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

thedata <- read.csv("~/Downloads/Vel.csv", header = TRUE)

thedata$newDate <- dmy_hms(thedata$Date)
ggplot(thedata, aes(newDate, Value)) +
    geom_point(thedata=thedata$ID %>% filter(thedata$ID == "A"))
```

But it plots all points (A and B IDs).

And it gives me

> "Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: thedata"

when using ggplot.

UPDATE

Using :

```
thedata <- read.csv("~/Downloads/Vel.csv", header = TRUE)
thedata <- as.data.frame(thedata)
thedata$newDate <- dmy_hms(thedata$Date)
ggplot(thedata, aes(newDate, Value)) +
    geom_point(data=thedata$ID %>% filter(thedata$ID == "A"))
```

hence, using data as data frame , and using `geom_point(data=thedata$ID %>%` instead of `geom_point(thedata=thedata$ID %>%` as @aosmith pointed,

results in :

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class ts

Comment: The argument is `data` not `thedata`.  You will need to pass a data.frame to that argument; in you current code it looks like you are working with a vector.

Comment: @aosmith:yes, I missed the `data` thing. I updated but still have an error.

Comment: Are you trying to use `filter` from dplyr or `filter` from stats?  If the former, it would be `thedata %>% filter(ID == "A")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is how you should do it :

```
ggplot(thedata %>% dplyr::filter(ID == "A"), aes(newDate, Value)) +
geom_point()
```

The point is that you can't specify a new dataframe in the `geom` when you specified one in ggplot(). I guess you could also do something like that :

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(data = thedata %>% dplyr::filter(ID == "A"), aes(newDate, Value))
```

**edit :**

I updated the second code block so it should work now.

About the filter() function, you don't need to pipe `thedata` in your case. This work just as well and is easier to read : `geom_point(data = filter(thedata, ID == "A"), aes(newDate, Value))`

Also, it's only my opinion but I guess it would be more interesting for you to plot the whole data and color by ID, like this :

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(data = thedata, aes(newDate, Value, colour = ID))
```

To finish on the question of feeding `ggplot()` with a dataframe, note that you can specify different `data` to all geom, as in this example with `mtcars` dataset :

```
ggplot() +
     geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = cyl)) +
     geom_point(data = filter(mtcars, cyl == 6), aes(qsec, drat))
```

Comment: Your last example won't work as written.  You need to explicitly write out the `data` argument or pass the dataset as the second argument in the function.  The `data` argument is *not* first in the geom layers, only in `ggplot`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.(upv).I was trying to load the data int the ggplot() in order to have them already because I may need besides geom_point, to add something else.So, I don't want to write again the data (newDate, Value).That's why I was trying `ggplot(thedata, aes(newDate, Value)) + geom_point(...)`,but I didn't want to use `aes(newDat, Value)` again.